# Display image by $id before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

In my commentary upload image system, its browse image and display it. If I browse a image in a comment, its also display all others comment's display field. Is it possible to display browse image only each comment separately by its own $id.

(N.B. comment field show/hide by its own $id, which is remove here for use)

This is my work http://jsfiddle.net/er9e72ww/2/

Now I want to use a $id for each preview like below:

```
//Preview want to Add '.$id.'
  <div class="output_rep'.$id.'" style="display:none;">
  <img class="preview_rep'.$id.'" src="" alt="No Image Found"/>
  </div>
```

Script that I tried( maybe wrong) not working

```
//preview image
$(".repfile").change(function(){
    var ID = $(this).attr('id').replace('','');
    previewPic(this);
});

function previewPic(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $(".preview_rep"+ID).attr('src', e.target.result);
        $(".output_rep"+ID).show();
        $(".replycom").focus();
        $('#img').hide();
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are passing the element to the other function you can get the ID from there.

```
$(".preview_rep" + input.id).attr('src', e.target.result);
$(".output_rep" + input.id).show();
```

No need to get the ID in your change handler.